# UIWindowlevel for the Touch ID alert

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

What is the exactly value for UIWindowLevel(CGFloat) of the Touch ID alert(the one that ask user to put finger on)?

Comment: Why do you need to know? You want be able to put anything on top of that.

Comment: yea. I was trying to put something on top of it and I tried to use the max float value but it won't work. You have any idea of how to do that?

Comment: You won't be able to do that. You might be able to hack into the window system and change the window level but that would get your app rejected. Actually, even trying to overlap that alert will probably get you rejected.

Comment: ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little meaningless because no matter what the value is, we can not do anything.

There are three default window level, and also developer can use CGFloat to customize the window level, but even you define the window level as max CGFloat your window will not be on top of any system alert.